# Ubuntu 14.04 running on VMware 11 : Touchpad scroll does not work

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, vmware, synaptics

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 as guest OS on VMWare workstation v11. Machine is a Lenovo z50-70 laptop. I haven't been able to scroll using the touchpad. I have to either use a usb mouse or the touchpad buttons to actually drag the scrollbar.

Have tried few suggestions like re-installing the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. But that was of little help.

Also I dont see any options for enabling/disabling scroll  which are usually there in the muose/touchpad settings.

[image]

Please suggest a working solution.

Comment: Try following 
"Launch VMWare workstation, click the Edit menu, then select Preferences. Now select the Devices Tab - You will see a checkbox "Disable Autorun on Host" turn this off, i.e take the check off, click apply and ok. Close down VMWare Workstation, reboot your machine"

Comment: Thanks @Aravinda, but that didn't helped. Still not able to scroll

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Workstation currently doesn't have native support for two finger scroll. You can switch to VirtualBox or install a third-party software on your host that emulates a scroll wheel.

Comment: can you suggest some third party tool for installation.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to use the arrow keys to work around the touchpad, it is incredibly frustrating but I am beginning to recognize that there is no fix for this.