# Scrolling with two fingers, I don't have that option

Tags: 20.04, scrolling

How can I enable two finger scrolling in Ubuntu 20.04?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1354224/edit) and add information about your distribution and version of Linux. Did you install it recently, or upgrade from a previous version? Did you have this option before? If so, did you install anything new?

Comment: I'm new to linux. I installed Ubuntu 20.042 LTS through VMware

Comment: Please add the information **inside the body of your question above**. If you don't tell us you are using VMware we won't know about it. Just a picture in the body of your question is not sufficient. Also check your VMWare settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable both: two finger scrolling and edge scrolling permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372988/enable-both-two-finger-scrolling-and-edge-scrolling-permanently)

Comment: This seems to be VMWare issue. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605643/ubuntu-14-04-running-on-vmware-11-touchpad-scroll-does-not-work) for more.